# Express.js routing. How to put a default route before all of my existing routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm probably phrasing this question wrong so please bear with me. So right now I have some routes:

localhost:3000/index

localhost:3000/home

localhost:3000/login

localhost:3000/forgot

but before every route in the URL, I want a client name like this:

localhost:3000/client/index

localhost:3000/client/home

localhost:3000/client/login

localhost:3000/client/forgot

Is there a good way to do this without manually changing all the route strings? And again sorry if I'm phrasing this question poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a router (router.js) with all those rules defined in it. Then reference in express app:

```
app.use('/client', require ('./router'));
```

You router file:

```
var router = require ('express').Router();

router.use('/index', ...);
...
module.exports = router;
```